# Clojure is-prime function?

Tags: clojure

I am doing `is-prime?` function that should return true if n is prime and false otherwise, it also should check to see if n is 1 or 2 and respond accordingly; if not, it should call `no-divisors` function. At the moment I get this output :

Can anyone see what's wrong, would be much appreciated

```
expected result is false,current false
expected result is true,current true
expected result is true,current false
expected result is false,current false
expected result is true,current false
```

no-divisors?

```
(->> (range 2 n)
(filter #(Divides % n))
empty? ))
(println (no-divisors? 4))
```

is-prime?

```
(defn is-prime? [n]
(and (< 1 n)
(not-any? (filter #(no-divisors? % n))
(range 2 n))))
(println  "expected result is false,current"( is-prime? 1))
(println "expected result is true,current"( is-prime? 2))
(println "expected result is true,current" ( is-prime? 3))
(println "expected result is false,current"( is-prime? 4))
(println "expected result is true,current"( is-prime? 101))
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable, show a [mcve], and note what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your `is-prime?` function? Since a prime is any number tha has no divisors, does it need to do anything apart from calling `no-divisors?` ?

Comment: `no-divisors` function should return true if none of the numbers between 2 and √ divide n, and false otherwise.

Comment: The problem is within  `is-prime` function somewhere, where the current output of some the tests are different to what they are supposed to be

Comment: Part of complying with "format your code so it's readable" is indentation.

Comment: Also, the `defn` with the signature for `no-divisors?` is missing.

Comment: ...and where is `Divides` supposed to come from? If you provided your `ns` block, we'd know, but without it, this code doesn't work for anyone but you.

Comment: Bigger-picture, though, is that ideally a question should be isolated to the simplest/narrowest possible thing. So if your question is why `(is-prime? 3)` is `false`, for example, you can start by breaking it down into simpler pieces (Is `(< 1 n)` what you expect? Is `(not-any? (filter #(no-divisors? % n)) (range 2 n))` what you expect? If `(filter #(Divides % n) (range 2 n))` isn't empty when you expect it to be, what is the specific value it contains?), and then eventually stop when you have a question about Clojure-the-language you need our help to answer.

Comment: ...which is to say -- you're expected to do the work of analyzing your own program's logic; when that analysis leads to a question that isn't about your own program, but is about the language/library/tools you're using, that question is more likely to be something that's helpful to others, and thus more likely to be welcomed and usefully answered here.

Comment: My problem is where I am having a different output to the actual required output, `/// current output///` (is-prime? 1)
 => false
(is-prime? 2)
 => true
(is-prime? 3)
 => false
(is-prime? 4)
 => false
(is-prime? 101)
 => false


`/// required output ///`
(is-prime? 1)
 => false
 (is-prime? 2)
 => true
 (is-prime? 3)
 => true
 (is-prime? 4)
 => false
 (is-prime? 101)
 => true
. As all the other functions work fine apart from `is-prime`. if you can spot anything wrong please point it out

Comment: I know what you're asking for, but what *we* ask for is narrow, specific questions, not "please debug my code for me".

Answer (score 3):

If you format your code per Clojure conventions, it's pretty clear what the problem is:

```
(defn is-prime? [n]
  (and (< 1 n)
       (not-any? (filter #(no-divisors? % n))
                 (range 2 n))))
```

You're calling `filter` with a single argument which with return a transducer. Your call to `not-any?` then tries to treat that transducer as a predicate and since a transducer, given a single argument, returns a function -- and a function is "truthy" (not `nil` or `false`) then `not-any?` will return `false` per its definition.

The reason it returns `true` for `2` is that `(range 2 2)` is an empty sequence and `not-any?` returns `true` for an empty sequence without calling the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Several people have asked you for complete, well-formatted code. Provide
  it. It will help you think clearly.
- Use `integer?` and `<` to make sure you are testing a possible prime.
- A prime is a number with no proper factors. Define it as such. You
  are doing the work twice - Russian doll style.
- It is easier to test your function on a range of possibles. I used `(filter prime? (range -20 20))`, yielding `(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19)`.

Name the function `prime?`. That's the Clojure convention. The initial `is-` is redundant. This may seem nit-picking, but simpler is clearer.

Best of luck!